# Javascript charts, custom step amount, but equally divided over available space

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, chartist.js

I'm looking for a javascript chart library where I can set custom step size.
I want a bar chart, where certain values are more important than others.

I'd like to have the ticks like [0, 50, 90, 99, 100]. And have the space between those values the same. I've tried Google Charts and Chartist, but they all put 99 and 100 very close to eachother, but I want it equally divided.

This is the idea:

[image: 100]
[image: 99]
[image: 80]

Anyone ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If these are your domain values, then provide them as strings instead of numbers.  Then they will be evenly distributed.

But if these are your target or range values, you'll have to do something trickier. You'll have to use integer values like 0 through 4, and then use the explicit ticks option for the vAxis to specify both the values and how to display them.

Comment: I don't think I really understand you. I've created a jsFiddle... Maybe you can explain yourself a bit more with this example? https://jsfiddle.net/tomhier/oqgogx90/

Comment: My suggestion was for using Google Charts.  If you make a jsfiddle using Google Charts along the same lines, I can modify it.